# Rails 3 Nested Attributes and Access Association Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-attributes

I have the following scenario:
A product can be sold by different providers for a given price.
In my form for the product, I want to select the providers through checkboxes and
assign a price for the selected providers.

My model:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price
  has_many :providers, through: :price

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :providers, :price
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  isbn       :integer
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
```

**provider.rb**

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price
  has_many :products, through: :price
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: providers
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
```

**price.rb**

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :provider
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: prices
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  value       :decimal(, )
#  created_at  :datetime        not null
#      updated_at  :datetime        not null
#  product_id  :integer
#  provider_id :integer
```

**app/views/products/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
...
<div class="field">
    <% Provider.all.each do |provider| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "product[provider_ids][]", provider.id, @product.provider_ids.include?(provider.id), id: dom_id(provider) %>
          <%= label_tag dom_id(provider), provider.name %>
    <% end %>

    <% f.fields_for :price do |price_form| %>
      <%= price_form.text_field :value %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
</div>
...
```

I didn't change anything in the products_controller.
I tried to access the association attribute price.value through the following code in my form.

```
<%= f.fields_for :price do |price_form| %>
    <%= price_form.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

But no text_field are displayed near the checkboxes and when I select one provider and submit the form, I get the following error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `price_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `belongs_to :price` in Product class into `has_one :price`. You should use `belongs_to :attribute` method on models which has `attribute_id` in its table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<% f.fields_for :price do |price_form| %>
    <%= price_form.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :price do |price_form| %>
    <%= price_form.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, this was just a typo. But this doesn't cause the problem.